# How can I split a list when it reaches a certain item and then return everything after including that item in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
    >>> last_phonemes(['AE1', 'B', 'S', 'IH0', 'N', 'TH'])
    ['IH0', 'N', 'TH']
    >>> last_phonemes(['IH0', 'N'])
    ['IH0', 'N']
    >>> last_phonemes(['B', 'S'])
    []
```

In this program I am looking for the last item that ends with 0,1 or 2 and return that item along with everything that comes after it

Answer (score 7):

This searches from the end of the list, returning the appropriate slice the first time it hits a match (and returning `[]` if it doesn't):

```
def last_phonemes(seq):
    for i, s in enumerate(reversed(seq), 1):
        if s.endswith(("0", "1", "2")):
            return seq[-i:]
    return []
```

Comment: Wow why didn't I think of returning the negative slice instead of trying to wrap with `len(seq)`? Good answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) function from the itertools package. For example:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'IH0', ['AE1', 'B', 'S', 'IH0', 'N', 'TH']))
['IH0', 'N', 'TH']
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'IH0', ['IH0', 'N']))
['IH0', 'N']
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda x: x != 'IH0', ['B', 'S']))
[]
```

Comment: Actually, it needs to be the last one that ends in "012". That'll teach me to read the question properly...

Comment: @srgerg which makes the function more like `[el for idx, el in dropwhile(lambda idx, el: any(ch.endswith(('0','1','2')) for ch in seq[idx+1:]), enumerate(seq))]` Yuck.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yuck indeed! Zero's answer is much better and even more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the list backwards, and return a sliced list:

```
def last_phonemes(lst):
    for i in xrange(len(lst)-1, -1, -1):
        if lst[i][-1] in "012":
            return lst[i:]
    return []
```

Replace `xrange` with `range` if you're using Python 3.

Comment: This would work better if you did `for i, el in enumerate(lst): if el[-2] in '012': return lst[i:]`, but even better if you could enumerate from the back!

Comment: You use xrange(len(lst) -1, -1, -1) to iterate backwards. Then either break or return when you find the first instance. edit: fixed args to xrange